# How to identify a string as being a byte literal?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

In Python 3, if I have a string such that:

```
print(some_str)
```

yields something like this:

```
b'This is the content of my string.\r\n'
```

I know it's a byte literal.

Is there a function that can be used to determine if that string is in byte literal format (versus having, say, the Unicode `'u'` prefix) without first interpreting? Or is there another best practice for handling this? I have a situation wherein getting a byte literal string needs to be dealt with differently than if it's in Unicode. In theory, something like this:

```
if is_byte_literal(some_str):
    // handle byte literal case
else:
    // handle unicode case
```

Comment: You *don't* have `some_str`, you have `some_bytes`!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The easiest and, arguably, best way to do this would be by utilizing the built-in [`isinstance`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance) with the `bytes` type:

```
some_str = b'hello world'
if isinstance(some_str, bytes):
    print('bytes')
elif isinstance(some_str, str):
    print('str')
else:
    # handle
```

Since, a byte literal will *always* be an instance of `bytes`, `isinstance(some_str, bytes)` will, of course, evaluate to `True`.

Comment: @Fardin yes, because byte aren't really byte literals in Python 2; using `b'...'` or `'...'` results in the same thing. In addition to that, this question explicitly asks for Python 3.

Answer (score 5):

Just to complement the other answer, the built-in [`type`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#type) also gives you this information. You can use it with `is` and the corresponding type to check accordingly.

For example, in Python 3:

```
a = 'foo'
print(type(a) is str)   # prints `True`
a = b'foo'
print(type(a) is bytes) # prints `True` as well
```

Comment: The reason to use `isinstance()` instead of comparing directly to `type`, is that [`isinstance()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance) will handle subclasses: a subclassed `bytes` object will still be valid as an instance of `bytes`, but not compare valid to the `bytes` type. Generally, `isinstance()` is therefore preferred.